# Can faulty SSD result in server restart?

Tags: ssd, failed

One of our servers faced random time restarts, we asked the dc to run hardware test and they said one of the SSD are likely failed. Could it be the reason for restarts in random times?

> We have completed testing of the system and we are showing that SDD is
>   showing signs of failure as shown by the following:
>
> Device Model:     Samsung SSD 840 EVO 500GB Serial Number:
>   S1DHNSAF218733W ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST
>   THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE 5
>   Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   098   098   010    Pre-fail  Always
>   -       135 9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   087   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       62573 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032
>   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       109 177
>   Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   001   001   000    Pre-fail  Always
>   -       1806 179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   098   098   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       135 181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032 
>   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0 182
>   Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always
>   -       0 183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   098   098   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       135 187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032 
>   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 190
>   Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   065   052   000    Old_age   Always
>   -       35 195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e
>   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 235
>   Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always
>   -       107 241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       269296231666
>
> This is most likely what is causing the reboots of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hardware failure can cause reboot, disk failure is critical and must be fix.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mentioned how you operate the SDD drive. In case you have several SSD drives and operate it in RAID (1+) one failed storage drive would not cause the server reboot - it would have impact on performance but not stability.

Anyway once you recognize failing device it is good idea to replace it. It can be critical but even it is redundant reducing redundancy getting you close to failure.